# Добавление в текстовые файлы два столбца с помощью BAT файла

Tags: bat

Привет. В общем есть родительский каталог, содержащий 182 папки (в каждой папке приблизительно 170 файлов). Так вот, папка представляет собой юзера, а каждый файл траекторию. Задача состоит в следующем добавить первый столбец в каждый текстовый файл с номером траектории по порядку (1, 2, 3, 4, ...), и второй столбец с номером папки, т.е. номером юзера (1, 2, 3, 4, ...). Это все можно было сделать в СУБД через запросы, но это займет колоссальное время.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что  робота за автора

Comment: @totorro работа за автора не является поводом для закрытия - http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: @PashaPash ознакомился